# Is returning an array by reference from a method more efficient?

Tags: php, arrays, return-by-reference, return-by-value

I have a function that returns an array. In PHP arrays are returned by value by default, unless the `&` operator is used. I assume when returning an array from a function by value results in a copy of the array being created. Is it therefore more efficient to return a reference to the array?

Comment: Comes under the category of micro-optimisation.... and no it doesn't; internally, PHP "returns" the actual array that was created inside the function, it doesn't copy anything.... and pass by reference/value has nothing to do with the value returned by a return statement, only with the arguments passed into the array

Comment: Good point - I was meant to write "In PHP arrays are **returned** by value..." instead of "In PHP arrays are **passed** by value...". I've corrected this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, according to the PHP documentation on [Returning References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), that the answer is 'No':

> Do not use return-by-reference to increase performance. The engine will automatically optimize this on its own. Only return references when you have a valid technical reason to do so.